# Excel COUNTIFS multiple and sequential criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Column **A** has: `Apples` `Oranges` `Pears` `Bananas` `Mangos` multiple times and in random orders.

Column **C** has: `Red` `Orange` `Yellow` `Blue` `Purple` corresponding to column **A** multiple times and in random orders.

I am looking for a formula which counts or sums all instances where `Pears` immediately follow `Apples` (i.e. the row below `Apples`) AND `Pears` are also `Orange`

I can return `Apples` and `Pears` and even `Pears` that are `Orange` but I cannot figure out how to return instances of `Pears` that are `Orange` which immediately follow `Apples`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() with ranges of the same size that are offset:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$1040000,"Apples",A$2:A$1040001,"Pear",C$2:C$1040001,"Orange")
```